# Python Need to convert a datetime object into RFC 1132 format

Tags: python, datetime, rfc

I am looking for a pythonic way of parsing a datetime object into an RFC 1132 compliant string:

Assuming (GMT)

So: 2008-10-22T10:52:40Z into Wed, 22 Oct 2008 10:52:40 GMT

I am sure there is a very simple way but i haven't been able to find it.

Thanks

Comment: You have different years in input (2015) and output (2008) dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could advise something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

date_str = '2008-10-22T10:52:40Z'

mytime = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
mytime = mytime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('GMT'))
print(mytime.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"))
# Output: Wed, 22 Oct 2008 10:52:40 GMT
```

List of formatting directives for `strftime` you could find [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).